# ASP.NET Core ResponseCacheAttribute - VaryByCustom?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, responsecache

I've been using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ResponseCacheAttribute` for the first time and have come across an issue that I would have solved previously using the `VaryByCustom` property in `OutputCache`in ASP.NET (and using `public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string s)` in the global.asax).

This VaryByCustom caching seems to no longer exist in ASP.NET Core. Is there a built-in alternative that I'm missing here or will I need to implement this myself to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you have two flexible options in ASP.NET core:

1. Use the `VaryByHeader` or `VaryByQueryKeys` if you're using the `ResponseCacheAttribute`.

When using Headers, you need to write the value to vary by as a header, which could be any arbitrary value (no need to expose data to the client):

```
Response.Headers.Add("X-My-Vary-Header", "this-is-variable");
```

In essence, this is all the `VaryByCustomString` ever did for you anyway. The way I see it, you're no longer forced to put this code in a specific method/file (e.g. global.asax).

2. Try the `<cache>` Tag Helper when caching in Razor.

Here you have a wide range of things to "vary" by: `vary-by-header`, `vary-by-route`, `vary-by-user`, and even a custom `vary-by`.

Have a look here and decide whether to use the attribute or the cache tag helper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/cache-tag-helper